# How to calculate value for an observation by group?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so:

```
mydf <- data.frame(group=c(rep("a", 4),rep("b", 4), rep("c", 4)), score=sample(1:10, 12, replace=TRUE))
mydf
   group score
1      a    10
2      a     9
3      a     2
4      a     3
5      b     1
6      b    10
7      b     1
8      b    10
9      c     3
10     c     7
11     c     1
12     c     3
```

I can calculate the mean of each group like so:

```
> by(mydf[,c("score")], mydf$group, mean)
mydf$group: a
[1] 6
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
mydf$group: b
[1] 5.5
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
mydf$group: c
[1] 3.5
```

But what I wish to do, is create a new column, say called `resdidual` which contains the residual from the mean of the group.  It would seem like there is some way to use one of the `apply` functions to do this, but for some reason I can't see it.

I would want my end result to look like so:

```
mydf
   group score residual
1      a    10        4
2      a     9        3
3      a     2       -4
4      a     3       -3
5      b     1     -4.5
6      b    10      4.5
7      b     1     -4.5
8      b    10      4.5
9      c     3      -.5
10     c     7      3.5
11     c     1     -2.5
12     c     3      -.5
```

Any ideas or pointers to the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: While using functions such as `sample` or `runif`, `dunif` etc. it is good to use `set.seed` beforehand, so then the results are replicable.

Comment: Yep, you might want to fix your example, mean(c(10,9,7,9)) == 6?

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected my data sorry for not using a random seed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
mydf$score - tapply(mydf$score, mydf$group, mean)[as.character(mydf$group)]
```

`tapply` works the same as `by` but with a nicer output. The `[as.character(mydf$group)]` subsets and replicates `tapply`'s output so that it aligns `mdf$group`.

Comment: `with(mydf, score - ave(score,group) )` would be easier than `tapply` as the order of the group variable won't matter.

Comment: This is `ave`some! I never bothered before with that function.

Comment: One of my favourites. It is literally the "split-apply-combine" logic that many of the d/plyr functions use.

Answer (score 2):

```
 library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(residual = score - mean(score))
```

I take the data, I group by `group`, then I add a column (using `mutate`) which is the difference between the variable `score` and the mean of that variable in each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(hash)
mydf <- data.frame(group=c(rep("a", 4),rep("b", 4), rep("c", 4)), score=sample(1:10, 12, replace=TRUE))
byResult <- by(mydf[,c("score")], mydf$group, mean)
h <- hash(keys= names(byResult), values =byResult)
residualsVar <- apply(mydf,1,function(row){
as.vector(values(h,row[1]))-as.numeric(row[2])
})
df <- cbind(mydf,residualsVar)
```